# sizeof(T) being interpreted as two arguments

Tags: c++, c++17

```
error: no matching function for call to 'operator new(sizetype, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int*&)'
 new(sizeof(T), tmp) T{std::move(buffer[i])};
```

I'm getting this error which leads me to believe that `sizeof(T)` is being interpreted as `sizetype, T`. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

`tmp` is of the type `T*`, the new operator is being defined by `#include <new>`, and I don't define the comma operator anywhere. When I googled this error the only similar occurrence I could find was debug mode redefining the new operator, but that isn't the case for this.

Comment: Crystal ball is out of service, please provide relevant code snippet.

Comment: That syntax does not look like something C++ code is likely to contain. Can you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: the relevant code snippet is in that error message, `new(sizeof(T), tmp) T{std::move(buffer[i])};`.

Comment: @Angew it's a placement new statement. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: LJTalbot, no, it is not. Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, SVP. Also, I can tell you with all certainty that @Angew knows what placement new is. If he is telling you the syntax looks weird, it is weird - but see my first point.

Comment: thats not how you do placement new. thats the signature of operator new. Just pass the address you want to place to, no size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're trying to write placement new, but you're passing one argument too many. When `operator new` is invoked via a `new` expression, the first argument is always set to the size of the type being new'ed. So your code translates to a call to

```
operator new(size_t, size_t, T*)
```

The first `size_t` is `sizeof(T)` provided by the language, the second is `sizeof(T)` provided by your expression, and the third is the pointer.

Normal syntax for placement new is this:

```
new (tmp) T{std::move(buffer[i])};
```

Comment: By replying to this badly formed question, you are promoting bad behavior (

Comment: @SergeyA It's far from stellar, but the question actually contains all the information necessary to answer it. Most MCVE-lacking questions are much worse. I can understand the downvotes (even though I wouldn't join them), but I disagree with the close votes here.

Comment: To me MCVE is binary. If the question asks about error message, not putting a smallest MCVE is just lack of respect, in my view. But of course, this is just my opinion, you certainly might not share it.

Comment: Sorry if my question was lackluster, thanks for being productive and answering it anyway instead of just complaining about the question itself.

Comment: Well you see above - the message was received. Now OP knows that following the rules is not necessary, someone will answer it anyway.

Comment: No, I now know what I needed to know as well as what I did wrong with this question to improve in future questions. I'm not quite following your logic?